# Design Bug: Featured tag color on bottom notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The [featured](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) and [status-complete](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-complete) tags need some tweaking for dark background:

[image]

Comment: Also, favicon isn't updated in the chatroom

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed. The change will be live after the next production build.